# Showing a different background color or layout beyond 80 column using spf13

Tags: vimrc, plugin-spf13

I've looked at [Vim 80 column layout concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns) and [Showing a different background colour in Vim past 80 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447109/showing-a-different-background-colour-in-vim-past-80-characters?lq=1) and tried the solutions provided there. They seem to work, however, only for some simple ordinary `.vimrc`'s, not for spf13.

When I add, say,

```
set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1
```

to a simple `.vimrc`, I get

[image]

But when I try to add these two lines to `~/.vimrc.local` (as mentioned in spf13) for customization, I get nothing. Do I need to set something else like `~/.vimrc.before`?

I'm not sure if my way of customization is too naive, or if there is already some instruction on this that I've missed. Has anyone succeeded in setting a different background color or layout for columns beyond 80 when using spf13? Thanks.

BTW I'm using VIM 7.3 on UBUNTU 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in Solarized. If I comment out `color solarized` in `.vimrc` it works.

On a normal vim install `:highlight ColorColumn` gives me:

```
ColorColumn    xxx term=reverse ctermbg=1 guibg=LightRed
```

And the `xxx` example shows a red background, but with Solarized it gives me:

```
ColorColumn    xxx ctermbg=235 guibg=DarkRed
```

and the `xxx` example shows as normal text (black on white in my case).

I didn't really investigate the cause of this; but I fixed it by adding this to the `.vimrc.local`:

```
set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1

highlight ColorColumn term=reverse ctermbg=1 guibg=LightRed
augroup colorcolumn
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme solarized highlight ColorColumn term=reverse ctermbg=1 guibg=LightRed
augroup end
```

The `autocmd` isn't strictly required, but if you change colour schemes all highlights are reset, so this makes sure it applies the fix again.

Comment: This seems still not working for me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @WanxinGao Does it work if you uncomment the `color solarized`? If not, try disabling the plugins that SPF13 includes and see if that fixes it...

Comment: Yeah. My bad. After commenting out `color solarized` it finally works. Actually I also uncommented it back and then it is now all OK with Solarized.